# Select objects within radius using longitude and latitude

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I wonder how I can create a query and select objects that are located within a radius of 50 km.

The information I can use is Longitude and latitude for every object. I would like to set my own location in the query and calculate the objects distance to my position based on its coordinates.

Comment: You need to download some geo location database which contains data based on lats and longs.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using a geography type, which you should be, use `STDistance` - see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933808.aspx

```
select *  
from yourtable
where place.STDistance(@myposition)<50000
```